# Reactjs, yarn etc

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I want to create a test React apllication but I am stuck at the installation:
I install Yarn with npm because the yarn msi doesn't start, so:

```
1. npm i .g yarnpkg
2. yarn create react-app test
```

and I read this error message:

> yarn create v0.15.1 error Couldn't find a package.json (or bower.json)
>   file in C:\Users***\React
>       at C:\Users***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarnpkg\lib\config.js:355:13
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (C:\Users***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarnpkg\node_modules\babel-runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
>       at C:\Users***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarnpkg\node_modules\babel-runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:28:13
>   info Visit http://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation
>   about this command.

I tried to search it on Internet but they did not solve my problem. Please, help me.

Comment: What? `.g` isn't how you globally install. [`yarnpkg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarnpkg) is deprecated. I'd recommend finding a good tutorial.

Comment: OK, thanks. I started it recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initiate a npm project first.

```
cd projectfolder
npm init
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me but there is another error: The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
  "babel-jest": "23.6.0"
Can you help me also with this error, please?

Comment: @SándorHatvani *what* error? If it requires a dependency, *did you try installing it*? Beware of being a [help vampire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem).

Comment: As @SándorHatvani saids, did you run yarn install ?

Comment: did you run yarn install inside the new my-app folder ?

Comment: Yes. I use VS Code and I run it in its terminal.

Comment: I tried this solution too but nothing: yarn remove react-aad-msal
add
"resolutions": {
"jest": "23.6.0",
"babel-jest": "23.6.0"
},
to package.json
yarn install
yarn add react-aad-msal

Comment: When I want to start the app: yarn start.

Comment: I put this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204598/required-babel-jest-dependency Thx.

Answer (score 6):

To anyone visiting this thread in 2021, it's very likely you're running
`yarn create-react-app my-app` instead of `yarn create react-app my-app`.