# Required babel-jest dependency

Tags: reactjs, babel-jest

I am new in the topic of React. I started it recently and I have a problem when I want to start a React app.
'yarn start' shows this error:

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency: "babel-jest": "23.6.0"
```

How can I overcome this error, please.

I tried to find a solution on Internet but I was not lucky. Where is the problem, please?

Comment: Really strange, what version of nodejs, operation system, ... do you have ? it should work without any error yarn create react-app my-app && cd my-app && yarn build && yarn start (tested with nodejs v10.15.0)

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I have v10.15.1. Sorry for late answer but there was not any computer nearby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it looks like what *might* have happened was that after you created a new app using `create-react-app`. you then manually added the `babel-jest` package with `yarn add babel-jest`. At least, that's how I was able to replicate on my machine the error that you quoted.

You do **not** need to add the `babel-jest` package manually, as it is already bundled into `create-react-app`. So, you need to follow the instructions that were provided alongside the above error in order to remove the package:

First, open `package.json` and remove the dependency line that includes `babel-jest`. It might look something like this:

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "babel",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",  <----------- REMOVE THIS LINE
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
```

Then, since you're using `yarn`, do the following from within your project root folder:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm yarn.lock
yarn install
```

This removes the manually added `babel-jest` package and then gives you a fresh install of all of the packages that originally came with `create-react-app` (which includes the `babel-jest` package that is already bundled in).

---

### Update

Based on your comment, I believe that has happened is this:

1. You used `npm init` which initialized a new nodejs project, with its own `package.json` file.
2. Then in that folder, you used `create-react-app` to create a `test` sub-folder - this initialized *another* project with its own `package.json` file.
3. For some reason, the project in the parent folder (which you initialized with `npm init`) has a reference to `babel-jest` - and this is conflicting with the app in the child folder which you created with `create-react-app`.

Keep in mind that `npm` and `yarn` are both package managers for nodejs projects. Each of them have an `init` command which can be used to initialize a new project, setting up a `package.json` file. For the most part, you will never need to use *both* `npm` and `yarn` within a single project. Just choose which one you want to use and stick with that one.

`create-react-app` is another command which can be used to initialize a new ReactJS project with a lot of initial setup built in. This has `babel-jest` built into it, which is what might be leading to some conflicts with the parent folder's `package.json` file or possibly a globally installed `babel-jest` package.

As a general rule, you should **only use 1** of the following:
  * `npm init` initializes a project at the current folder.
  * `yarn init` initializes a project at the current folder.
  * `create-react-app .` initializes a project at the current folder.

For your current situation, since you are working with a new project, I would recommend that you try to start over in initializing a new `create-react-app` project. Go to the parent folder, outside of the one where you used the `npm init` command. Create a project folder, and then in that folder, run `create-react-app .`

Comment: No. I have created a node app: npm init. Then I install yarn in the app folder: npm i -g yarn. Then I run yarn create-react-app test. Then I wanted start the app: yarn start. :)

Comment: @SándorHatvani Updated my answer based on your comment. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wanted to give it up. But Can I have one more question, please? Why yarn create react-app Test command create a subfolder into my Test folder? When I run this command without app name it gives me an error.

Comment: You can use `create-react-app` directly without using `yarn`. You'll notice also that `create-react-app` takes an argument, which is the folder where the new project should reside. If you put `.`, then it will be the current folder. If you put `test`, then it will create a subfolder called `test` and build your project there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am happy for you to be so helpful.

Comment: First of all - great answer! Second, I'm afraid I have the same issue, but I cannot afford recreating the project from scratch. Anything I can do in this situation to permanently solve this issue?